# Any $A$-homomorphism $ψ : A ⊗_k U → V$ is, by a standard adjunction, equal to $ψ(a ⊗ u) = aμ(u)$ for some $k$-linear map $π : U → V$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a symmetric $k$-algebra. Let $U, V$ be $A$-modules. Any $A$-homomorphism $ψ : A ⊗_k U → V$ is, by a standard adjunction, equal to $ψ(a ⊗ u) = aμ(u)$ for some $k$-linear map $π : U → V$.

In the book, standard adjunction always refers to the hom-tensor adjointness. But I tried hom-tensor adjunction and it didn't give a linear map between $U,V$. So I don't understand this equation: $ψ(a ⊗ u) = aμ(u)$ now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tensor-hom adjunction gives
$$ \mathrm{Hom}_A(A\otimes_kU,V) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_k(U,\mathrm{Hom}_A(A,V)). $$
Here you should note the subscripts, saying which maps are $A$-linear, and which are just $k$-linear. Next, there is a standard isomorphism
$$ \mathrm{Hom}_A(A,V) \xrightarrow\sim V, \quad f \mapsto f(1). $$
Putting this together gives you that
$$ \mathrm{Hom}_A(A\otimes_kU,V) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_k(U,V), $$
Sending a $k$-linear map $f\colon U\to V$ to the $A$-linear map
$$ A\otimes_k U \to V, \quad a\otimes u \mapsto af(u). $$